# Can you push only a specific view up when soft keyboard shows?

Tags: java, android, anchor, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

When a soft keyboard shows up, I want my `EditText` to be pushed up so it's at the top of my keyboard, but not anything else. I can get `adjustPan` working fine but that slides the root view up.

Is there any way to do this? Basically what I need to do is anchor an `EditText` to the top of the soft keyboard.

I noticed SnapChat animates their `EditText` down to the top of the soft keyboard when typing, so it must be possible.

Comment: Somebody must have a solution to this..I imagine this is a fairly common situation.

Comment: So, are you saying that you want the EditText to become the only widget on the screen, besides the keyboard?  Aside from that, you do realize that whatever EditText you tap will be scrolled to stay in view once the keyboard pops up.  Also, when the keyboard pops up, your activity height shrinks - you might be able to use that info.

Comment: All I want is for everything to stay the same (do not shift the whole activity up), and then create an `EditText` that is anchored to the top of the keyboard. This isn't exactly my case, but a good example would be press a button and an `EditText` appears anchored to the top of the soft keyboard. Technically in my case make the `EditText` visible again, not create it every time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I propose this: Create a popup dialog that is nothing but the edit text and use gravity (or other alignment) to force it to the bottom of its available area.  That would be equivalent to anchoring it to the keyboard.

I'm sure there's a way to control how the activity shrinks when the keyboard pops up, but that is probably a bad battle to fight.  Better let Android do what it wants.